# Javascript Framework for UI's

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frameworks

I need an open source Javascript framework to create web UI's. I'm looking for something similar to ExtJS but easier.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What are your requirements? What's wrong with normal HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to make HTML easier trying not to deal with divs, grids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all depends on your requirement only... How your application architect flow goes.
Please refer below link with list of few framework.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheBigGlossaryOfOpenSourceJavaScriptAndWebFrameworksWithCoolNames.aspx

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/11/top-10-javascript-frameworks-by-google.html

My suggestion is go for extjs(Even if you pay for it).

All the best.

Comment: Paying it's not a problem if it worth it. As I said, I'm looking sor something easier than extjs, with less functionalities

Comment: Thats Great @goblinch, thanks for your response. Did you go through the first link which i posted, that will contain the description of each framework. I hope that will help to find your requirement. Also consider second one too which contain detail description with limited list.

Comment: The only one I didn't knew is qooxdoo. It's seems what I'm looking for so I'll give it a try

Comment: Thats cool @goblinch. All the best!!!

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try to work with Webix http://webix.com/.
It is easy to learn thanks to detailed and comprehensive documentation and with this library you can build web apps of any difficulty.